# How to disable all WordPress emails modularly and programatically?

Tags: filters, hooks, email

I want to modularly disable emails sent out by WordPress so I can replace them with my own custom emails when necessary.

I tried googling for a list of filter hooks, but couldn't find anything as comprehensive as I would like. I found these two so far:

```
/**
 * Disable default WordPress emails.
 */
add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'send_email_change_email', '__return_false' );
```

Is there a resource or a list of all filter hooks that WordPress uses to send emails?

### Update

Another option, as mentioned in [kirillrocks's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/302193/22588) is to completely disable the `wp_mail()` function. However, this is undesirable for my use case as it disables ALL emails. For my use case, I would like to disable all mails individually, so I can later 'overwrite' them with my own emails, but still use the `wp_mail()` function to send them.

Answer (score 15):

**Option 1**: Remove the 'to' argument from `wp_mail` function in WordPress, it will keep your system running without sending any default WordPress emails.

```
add_filter('wp_mail','disabling_emails', 10,1);
function disabling_emails( $args ){
    unset ( $args['to'] );
    return $args;
}
```

The `wp_mail` is a wrapper for the `phpmailer` class and it will not send any emails if there is no recipient.

**Option 2:** Hook to the phpmailer class directly and `ClearAllRecipients` from there

```
function my_action( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->ClearAllRecipients();
}
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_action' );
```

**Option 3**: Keep using `wp_mail` for your own needs but disable for everything else.

```
add_filter('wp_mail','disabling_emails', 10,1);
function disabling_emails( $args ){
    if ( ! $_GET['allow_wp_mail'] ) {
        unset ( $args['to'] );
    }
    return $args;
}
```

and when you are calling `wp_mail` use it like this:

```
$_GET['allow_wp_mail'] = true;
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
unset ( $_GET['allow_wp_mail'] ); // optional
```

https://react2wp.com/wordpress-disable-email-notifications-pragmatically-in-code-fix/

You are welcome!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I stumbled upon this option as well, but doesn't this remove the `wp_mail` functionality altogether? I want to replace the default mails with my own, but still use the `wp_mail` function. Perhaps I should have mentioned that in the question... Still appreciated though!

Comment: Updated with option #3

Comment: Thanks kirillrocks for this help. option #2 works perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

to change the content of the "change password" email and the "change email" email, you can use the filter ["password_change_email"](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/password_change_email/) and ["email_change_email"](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/email_change_email/).

An example for the "password_change_email" filter:

```
function my_change_email($pass_change_email, $user, $userdata )
{   
   $pass_change_email['message'] = "Hello this is my email content.";

   return $pass_change_email;
}


add_filter( 'password_change_email', 'my_change_email' );
```